# Single call ternary operator

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) now supports the [null coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator)

```
var item = aVal ?? aDefaultVal;
```

I might be overlooking something obvious, but is there something similar for the ternary operator, such that instead of doing

```
var item = aclass.amethod() > 5 ? aclass.amethod() : 5;
```

it wouldn't be needed to call `amethod()` twice?

Comment: Do you mean the *ternary* operator? :)

Comment: Just FYI, that operator is a *coalesce* operator.  Much like the `COALESCE()` we see in SQL.

Comment: moo, that is correct, is there a similar .net function for coalesce? and prefereably a shortcut version?

Comment: wow i did call it tertiary didn't i :)

Comment: moo- actually the ?? is the coalesce op, but the one I'm after would look for true result of an aoperator, instead of looking for non-null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**There is no such operator built into C#.**

While I would *select one of the other* answers (the one that uses `Math.Max` is arguably more clear for the example posted), this is here just to show another method. It's a shame that the computation requires an explicitly-typed variable.

```
Func<int,int> computation = (x) => x > 5 ? x : 5;
var item = computation(aclass.amethod());
```

And in-line, which is just ugly in C#.

```
var item = ((Func<int,int>)((x) => x > 5 ? x : 5))(aclass.amethod());
```

Of course both of the above really boil down to just:

```
var item = DoComputation(aclass.amethod());
```

And utilize the fact that C# does not use pass-by-name :-)

Or, perhaps an extension method:

```
static class Ext {
  public static TO Apply<TI,TO> (this TI obj, Func<TI,TO> fn) {
    return fn(obj);
  }
}

// note C# now lets us get away with no explicit Func<...> type
var item = Ext.Apply(aclass.amethod(), x => x > 5 ? x : 5);

// or as extension method -- imagine computation is as it was in the
// first example, or a compatible method group
var item = aclass.amethod().Apply(computation);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: the extension method route is the closest to a solution. Thanks

Comment: @boomhauer Take care with "being too tricky". It's easy to go wild with extension methods -- but at the end of the day, C# is C# (and not F# or Scala or language-X ;-)

Comment: I agree completely, but just got tired of creating temp vars all over the place to work around this one ;)

Answer (score 28):

```
var item = Math.Max(5, aclass.amethod());
```

Comment: uwe, works for this particular math funciton, but i'm seeking a more generic way. I'll update the question, thanks.

Answer (score 26):

How about:

```
var result = aclass.amethod();
var item = result > 5 ? result : 5;
```

You only need to call `aclass.amethod()` once, then.

Comment: and +1 for what should have been obvious

Comment: guys come on, im asking if there's a single call way of doing this. of course you can define a temp var.

Comment: You're right, going the whole Extension route is a lot better and clearer than just using a temporary variable.

Comment: my point is, the temp var is the solution i was looking for a shortcut to avoid, so while extension methods are not extremely user friendly, they appear to be the only thing that comes close to the ternary operator, can be called in one line, and without leaving temp var litter behind. Would still be nice to have a cleaner method that could be built into .net, but apparently doesnt exist.